# Core i3770k running too hot?

Tags: cpu, cooling, overclocking

I just installed a Core i7 3770K. I have a Corsair H60 Hybrid CPU cooler with fans on both sides of the radiator for a push/pull configuration. I have the airflow for the radiator pulling in air from outside the case. My no load temps are about 37-42 C. I converted a MKV yesterday to M4V to test the CPU and temperatures were up around 78 C. The TCASE on Itel's website is 67.4 C. Would that indicate I installed the heatsink poorly? I haven't even begun to overclock it!

http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/

I did see this post for the Core i7 940 from a while back... but I didn't know how the Ivy Bridge compared...

[Is my i7 CPU running too hot?](https://superuser.com/questions/34218/is-my-i7-cpu-running-too-hot)

Comment: I've got a Core i5-3570K and it's running at 17C idle and about 25C when I use Handbrake. I have no experience of the i7 chipset but, based on my experience with the i5, that sounds rather hot.

Comment: Ivy Bridge runs hotter then Sandy Bridge.  You cannot compare the two idle temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

I put an Intel watercooler on my i7 3770K. But the temperature was high, like yours. (60-70 C under load)

Examining I found that 1 of the 4 screws used to attach the pump to the CPU was misaligned. Correcting this the CPU the load temperature never went above 50.