# Average CPU core temperature of 60 °C is normal?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, cpu, gpu, temperature

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 running on an laptop with an Intel Core i5 and hybrid gpu.
I set my OS to boot with the discrete GPU device turned off, so working with integrated GPU and both cores of my CPU are showing around 60°C degrees. 
If I turn on the discrete GPU the temp goes high incresing past 100°C.
Is it safe the 60°C average for the cores?

Comment: Are we talking idle or 100% usage

Comment: @Ramhound I'm talking idle

Comment: ~55 is not abnormal. Your temperature is not ideal, but tolerable. By the way, search for similar questions on this site. You will find that this issue has been addressed previously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is my i7 CPU running too hot?](http://superuser.com/questions/34218/is-my-i7-cpu-running-too-hot)